# Marker click event is not overwriting between layers

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-marker

I'm using Mapbox one my client projects. Here I have facing one issue with click event.

Actually I have using two layers to load two different type of data layer 2 is over lapping layer 2. And each layer have markers with relative click events.

Issue is when both layer1 and layer2 markers are in same coordinates layer2 marker is over lapping layer1's marker. But while click on layer2 marker it is also triggering layer1 click event. How to prevent this?

My Code:

```
map.addLayer({
  id: 'layer1',
  type: 'circle',
  source: 'allPanels',
  'source-layer': self.mapLayers['allPanels']['source-layer'],
  minzoom: 7,
  paint: {
    'circle-opacity': 0.2,
    'circle-radius': {
      'base': 2,
      'stops': [[9, 2], [11, 4]]
    },
    'circle-color': '#878787'
  }
});
map.on('mouseenter', 'layer1', function () {
  self.map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';
});
map.on('mouseleave', 'layer1', function () {
  self.map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
});
map.on('click', 'layer1', function(){
    console.log("clicked layer 1")
});

map.addLayer({
  id: 'layer2',
  type: 'circle',
  source: 'allPanels',
  'source-layer': self.mapLayers['allPanels']['source-layer'],
  minzoom: 7,
  paint: {
    'circle-opacity': 0.2,
    'circle-radius': {
      'base': 2,
      'stops': [[9, 2], [11, 4]]
    },
    'circle-color': '#878787'
  }
});
map.on('mouseenter', 'layer2', function () {
  self.map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';
});
map.on('mouseleave', 'layer2', function () {
  self.map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
});
map.on('click', 'layer2', function(){
    console.log("clicked layer2")
});
```

Any one can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use the version of map.on which doesn't take a layer argument https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#on then filter out the layers you want and pick the single feature from the list of features.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you're looking for is event.stopPropagation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

It will stop the click from 'bubbling' past one layer.